# Replacing backslashes using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following text and I'm trying to get rid of `\'`. Desired output is `"Gigi DAgostino"`.

```
"Gigi D\'Agostino"
```

I've checked several other questions regarding replacing backslashes with `preg_replace`, and learned that I need to double escape it. So I've done some experiments.

```
echo preg_replace("/\\\/",   "", "Gigi D\'Agostino");   // Gigi D'Agostino
echo preg_replace("/'/",     "", "Gigi D\'Agostino");   // Gigi D\Agostino
echo preg_replace("/\\\\'/", "", "Gigi D\'Agostino");   // Gigi DAgostino
```

So far, so good. These make sense. But in my actual code, I've used single quotes for the patterns.

```
echo preg_replace('/\\\/',    "", "Gigi D\'Agostino");  // Gigi D'Agostino
echo preg_replace('/\'/',     "", "Gigi D\'Agostino");  // Gigi D\Agostino
echo preg_replace('/\\\\\'/', "", "Gigi D\'Agostino");  // Gigi DAgostino
```

Again, first two make sense. I don't get the third one. Why does it require an extra slash?

```
'/   (\\)->\       (\)->'    /'
      ^             ^
      |             |
   these two      this one
   escape the     escapes
   next \         the following '
```

What's the role of the extra (5<sup>th</sup>) `\`?

I'm not very familiar with regex, so I might be missing something really simple here.

PS: I'm not looking for a way to replace backslashes. The above examples already do that. I'm trying to understand the way it does.

---

```
$str = "Gigi D\'Agostino";

# \ escapes '
echo preg_replace('/\'/', "", $str) . PHP_EOL;  # "Gigi D\Agostino"

# can't escape \ with a single \. it requires two \
echo preg_replace('/\\/', "", $str) . PHP_EOL;  # No ending delimiter '/' found

# \\ escapes the third \
echo preg_replace('/\\\/', "", $str) . PHP_EOL; # "Gigi D'Agostino"

# now we combine the patterns. we replace \'
# we need to escape both \ and '
# double backslashes to escape \, and a single backslash to escape '
# makes four backslashes and an apos: \\\ \'
# but ofc, this doesn't work. requires an additional \
echo preg_replace('/\\\\\'/', "", $str) . PHP_EOL;  # "Gigi DAgostino"
```

Comment: Any reason not to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php?

Comment: In single quoted strings the backslash *escapes itself* and the single quote. PCRE just needs an escaped backslash. Simply `print` out your strings to see into which actual string values they've been tokenized.

Comment: @chris85 I'm also stripping/replacing other characters which I keep in a 2D array [pattern, substitute]. Besides, I like to get to the bottom of things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_replace() function

```
echo str_replace("\'","","Gigi D\'Agostino")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start of with a single quoted delimited pattern such as `'/'/'` (without escaping anything), you'll notice the delimiter `/` is outside of the single quoted pattern, which causes an error. By escaping `'` using `\`, the delimiter comes back into the single quoted pattern and the single quote is escaped. If you continue that process using the pattern `\'` it should become obvious what is happening, as well as notice a pattern within that process itself.

```
     '/'/' - error: / delimiter outside of pattern
    '/\'/' - escape '
   '/\\'/' - escape \, unescape ', error: / delimiter outside of pattern
  '/\\\'/' - escape ', unescape \
 '/\\\\'/' - escape \, unescape ', error: / delimiter outside of pettern
'/\\\\\'/' - escape ', escape \
```

If you continued and added another `\` to the pattern guess what's going to happen? yep, delimiter outside of pattern... hope this sheds a little bit of light on what is going on.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I still can't wrap my head around it. Doing an experiment by adding/removing "\" to the pattern would just only give me the end result. I'm not interested in that. I want to know about the escaping process. See the update. Hope it's clear enough to show where my confusion rises from.